# validate tags inside anchor

Tags: html, anchor, w3c-validation

Till now i know that inside `<a>` you can place a `<span>` which is perfectly **HTML Validate**

But what about other tags like:- `div, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video`and so on

Is their any specification on selecting the tag inside an anchor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML specifications describe this.

See [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2):

> ```
> <!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- anchor -->
> ```

(Follow the link to see a version with hyperlinks. In the spec itself `%inline` is linked to its expansion).

See [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model:
>   [Transparent](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#transparent), but there must be no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.